# Reconnecting hyperlink in Dynamic Hyperlink mxd in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hyperlink

Is there a way to reconnect the Hyperlink in a [Dynamic Hyperlink](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm#GUID-6C5E494B-D983-4666-A738-0EA6D1751D17)?

The situation is one of my workers was linking polygons to pdfs with Dynamic Hyperlink because each polygon had several pdfs that needed to be link.

The person sent me the mxd, and shapefile used for the Dynamic Hyperlink however the path to bring up the pdfs are not the same. The worker used his local drive and I trying to setup the link through our network so other workers can view the link pdfs. 
Is there way to edit the path in a mxd file or the map properties to fix the link between the polygons and pdfs.

We are using basic ArcMap for the project.

Comment: Multiple documents hyperlinked? Do you have multiple field s with hyperlinked? Anyway, replace paths to network folders, keeping document name. Very basic field calculator exercise

Comment: No only field with the hyperlinked. How do you change the network path in Dynamic Hyperlink?

Comment: See my answer.  You can't edit existing dynamic hyperlinks.

Answer (score 1):

If you had defined the hyperlinks in a field, it would be easier to fix.  As felix said, you could just do a simple replace operation on the field.  However, since you are using dynamic hyperlinks, these are all stored in the layer.  You can add or remove them, but I'm not sure you'll be able to fix the existing ones.  You may actually have to replace all the links manually so they are using the network locations.  To manage the dynamic hyperlinks, select the identify tool, identify the layer, right click on the feature in the identify box, select 'manage hyperlinks'.

I was not able to edit the hyperlinks once they were created.

This article explains hyperlinks in detail, and all the options you have for managing them.  To avoid this happening again, look at the advanced hyperlink functionality.  You can create a library of hyperlinks and use a script to access it for each feature.  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm#GUID-A8DBDEE3-72BA-4B65-A6B6-5FC87492A83F