# Selecting more than one document in Dynamic Hyperlink?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hyperlink

I am redoing the [Dynamic Hyperlinks](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm#GUID-6C5E494B-D983-4666-A738-0EA6D1751D17) in a Geodatabase as suggested in [Reconnecting hyperlink in Dynamic Hyperlink mxd in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/206007/115)

Can you select more than one document when you select the Add New button?

It seems you can add one document at a time. I would like to select more than documents when the Add Hyperlink menu link to a Document.

I would think there would be way of adding more than document instead of closing and reopening the Add New button.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in both, the help file and the FelixIP's comment in your previous post, this facility let's you to pick only one document. However, in the **Using parameters to control how a program opens a hyperlinked document** and **Advanced hyperlink functionality** sections of the help page, it is said that there are somewhat advanced functionalities whose usage is not as straightforward as selecting the to-be-hyperlinked document. Having said that, I can think of two options for your questions:

- Creating batch files (i.e., .BAT) for each feature, pointing to the files that you want to open in one-go, as explained [here](http://www.instructables.com/community/how-to-open-two-word-files-in-command-prompt/) and giving hyperlinks to these BAT files;
- Listing all relevant documents separated by a delimiter in a field
  and looping through by using VB or Python function as given in the
  **Advanced hyperlink functionality** section of the help page. Say, your files are C:\filename1.mxd and C:\filename2.mxd for a polygon/row.
  If you create a text field large enough to contain these paths (including
  the delimiters) and concatenate with | as in
  `C:\filename1.mxd|C:\filename2.mxd` and finally use the Python script
  below in Hperlinks>Script section, ***theoretically*** you should be able to open these
  two documents with default program associated with MXD file.

> ```
> import webbrowser
> def OpenLink([Formatted_Lot_Plan]):
>     for path in [Formatted_Lot_Plan].split("|"):
>         webbrowser.open(path)
>     return
> ```

Comment: +1 . Anyway i found that fastest thing to do is moving documents in dedicated folder and create hyperlink to it.